# How to make a method return the type which is "saved" in a static property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a Typescript beginner and want to do something of the following:

```js
class Field {
  static type = Object

  sanitize (a) {
    return this.constructor.type(a) // .valueOf() <-- as a bonus
  }
}

class NumberField extends Field {
  static type = Number
}
```

However, I have no idea how to type this. I tried generics but it complained that I cannot access T in a static property. I also tried a generic constructor function like this:

```js
function Field<T = typeof Object> (type: T) {
  return class Field {
    sanitize (a) {
      return type(a) // .valueOf() <-- as a bonus
    }
  }
}
```

but whatever I do it keeps complaining that T (which is `ObjectConstructor`) is not callable or (when used with new) has no construct signature. Its a bit strange that even `ObjectConstructor` doesnt have a construct signature.

I am now wondering how I could type this in a nice (maybe no too complicated) way.

// For the Bonus:
The `valueOf()` would convert any `Number` to `number` or any `Object` to `object`. If this would also work correctly that would be even better

Comment: I think it really *shouldn't* be a `static` field anyway. To me, `const objectField = new Field<Object>(Object);` and `const numberField = new Field<Number>(Number)` makes much more sense. Don't use inheritance there.

Comment: Interesting thought. I guess you are right. However, even without inheritance and not using the static property I had the problem that it wouldn't let me call `type` as a function

Comment: Your problem is partially confusing generic type constraints with generic type defaults. `T = typeof Object` is very different from `T extends typeof Object`. Almost certainly you wanted either `T extends typeof Object` or `T extends typeof Object = typeof Object`.

Comment: Well as I said: I am a beginner and even if I tried to learn this a few times already, I can't wrap my head around generics and extends...

Comment: If you use `type: typeof T;` (where `T` is instantiated to `Object` or `Number`) I think it should work.

Comment: @Bergi Whenever I tried to do that it said I couldn't use the type as a value

Comment: Oh right. `T extends (x: any) => any` does work, but is not particularly useful I guess.

Comment: I ended up doing it completely separate with only one class and passing the type to the constructor